# Delete Rest API specifying time period without using Artifact Cleanup Plugin and JFrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm quite new with Artifactory, and I was trying to delete some artifacts to make a sort of clean up of the old artifacts I don't use anymore.

I've found some solutions:

1. Using Artifact Cleanup Plugin, but I can't use it, as I'm not an Admin user in Artifactory and I can't install it. Plus, it isn't already installed, so I can't use it
2. Delete operation through JFrog CLI. I can't use it, as it isn't installed and I can't install it by myself

The only thing I can do by myself is calling the JFrog Rest Api through curl as documented in the following page:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API?_gl=1*1q2oqbv*_ga*MTc5MDMxODk1Mi4xNjU2MzIxMjEx*_ga_SQ1NR9VTFJ*MTY2NzU4MDA0MS41NS4xLjE2Njc1ODAwODAuMjEuMC4w#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteBuilds

My question is if I could use, without plugins or the JFrog CLI, any sort of parameter in my DELETE request in which I can specify, for example, an amount of "months" or "days" to filter what I would like to delete from Artifactory.

Actually I'm using this string, which only deletes that specified "folder":

```
 curl -u artifactory_user:artifactory_password -X DELETE https://website/artifactory/repositoryname/folder
```

Do these parameters exist?

Can you provide me an example of how could I integrate them in my request?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to install JFrog CLI on JFrog server.

1. You can install on your local computer bt referring to [this link](https://jfrog.com/getcli/).
2. Validate if cli is installed by running the command 'jfrog' from your command prompt. You need to [authenticate](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Authentication) to Artifactory from CLI.
3. Create a file with a name input.spec with the below contents.

   {
   "files": [
   {
   "aql": {
   "items.find": {
   "repo": "test-repository",
   "$or": [
   {
   "$and": [
   {
   "modified": { "$lt": "2022-10-01T21:26:52.000Z"}
   }
   ]
   }
   ]
   }
   }
   }
   ]
   }
4. Run the below command to verify if this is resulting in correct file list from the repository that we want.

   jfrog rt s --spec input.spec

This gives you the list of the files that are uploaded to the repository test-repository, before the date 2022-10-01.

5. Run the below query to actually delete the above listed files.

   jfrog.exe rt del --spec input.spec

This will delete the artifacts that are older than 2022-10-01 from the repository test-repository. You can modify the above input.spec file according to your need and run the same command.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but unfortunately I'm not working on an only local application. My application is deployed on a remote Bamboo, so for sure I can try JFrog CLI on my machine, but it doesn't solve my problem, because I have to manage the deletion process in my build.gradle during the Bamboo pipeline build process.